# How to customize DataGridViewButton cell according to the another column value in a dataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a DataGridView and then data retrieve for it manually in coding. Also, I added a DataGridViewButtonCell and it is working fine. But I wanted to customize it as according to another column(Status Column index of 4) value.

ex. 
- If Status Column value is "New" wanted to show form1
- If Status Column value is "Open" wanted to show form2
- If Status Column value is "Assigned" wanted to show form3
- If Status Column value is "Duplicate", "Postponed", and "Duplicate" wanted to show form4

How do I do this process? This is an image of the data grid view

![1]: https:C:\Users\kularathna\Desktop\New.PNG

## This is code for retrieve data to dataGridView

```
private void TesterHome_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Retriewe Data from database to the grid view
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source= LAPTOP-J70EHC58 ; Initial Catalog= Defect_Management_system ; Integrated Security = True ; Connect Timeout = 30 ; ");
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        string sqlstmt = SELECT * FROM defect WHERE tester_id = '"+ 5 +"' ;
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlstmt, con);
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            con.Close();
            dgvTester.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error + "Invalid");
        }

        // Insert Data Grid View Button
        DataGridViewButtonColumn dgvbtnColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        dgvTester.Columns.Add(dgvbtnColumn);
        dgvbtnColumn.HeaderText = " ";
        dgvbtnColumn.Text = "View";
        dgvbtnColumn.Name = "dgvBtn";
        dgvbtnColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
    }

    // Code for grid view button cell
    private void dgvTester_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
            if (senderGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewButtonCell)
            {
               //if(senderGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewTextBoxCell.Value  = "New")
                {
                    QA_ReviewForm qa = new QA_ReviewForm();
                    qa.Show();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error + "Invalid");
        }

    }
```

I was tried using
 if(senderGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewTextBoxCell.Value  = "New")  line 
 but it is not working

Comment: `it is not working` what does it mean? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes shows error in that line

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Is that code wrong? How do I customize it according to the status column value

Comment: If it is not working as expected so it is wrong. If you share what error you are getting then proper solution can be suggested.

Comment: class System.Windows.Form.DataGridViewTextBoxCell       Displays editable text information in a DataGridView control.  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property "DataGridViewCell.Value"

Comment: Replace `//if(senderGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewTextBoxCell.Value  = "New")` with `if((senderGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewTextBoxCell).Value  == "New")` That should solve your issue

Comment: Now shows this error ....class System.Windows.Form.DataGridViewTextBoxCell Displays editable text information in a DataGridView control.Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left-hand side to type 'string'

Comment: I fixed it adding ToString but when I click the button show this error System.NullReferenceException: Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Can you share the updated code in the question?

Comment: if ((senderGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewTextBoxCell).Value.ToString() == "New")

Answer (score 0):

In the code you shared has build error and the logic error too.

You are binding datatable to the GridView and adding one ButtonColumn to the GridView. When the button is clicked on that column you want to display different Forms based on the value of "Status" column.

In your code you are trying to compare the value of ButtonColumn. ButtonColumn does not have any value because it is not bound to any column from the DataTable.

You need to get the value of the "Status" column of the GridView and then compare its value.

You need to have following code in `CellContentClick` event handler. The code is example code. You need to change as per your need.

```
private void dgvTester_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (senderGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewButtonCell)
        {
             // "3" in following `if` condition is the column index of "Status" column.
             // You need to put appropriate column index here.
               var selectedStatus = senderGrid[3, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                if (selectedStatus  == "New")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("New");
                }
                else if (selectedStatus == "Open")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Open");
                }
                else if (selectedStatus == "Assigned")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Assigned");
                }
                else if (selectedStatus == "Duplicate")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate");
                }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception error)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(error + "Invalid");
     }
 }
```

This should help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: I replaced it but when I click the button nothing happens. What can I do now

Comment: I updated the code. Debug the code and check what value you are getting in `selectedStatus` variable.

Comment: When click the button nothing happen any thing

Comment: Do you know how to debug the code? Either the `dgvTester_CellContentClick_1` is not being executed at all or `selectedStatus` has some entirely different value. Debugging only can help you here.

Comment: No, I'm New to this. But I tried. I'm using visual studio so I add breakpoints in the left-hand corner and run the program. but arrow not coming to the message box rows

Comment: the arrow coming to each condition row but not coming to the message box rows.

Comment: What value you have in `selectedStatus` ? Did you put correct columnIndex instead of `3` in `senderGrid[3, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();` ?

Comment: table has several status value when load but when click the button nothing hapen and in the code not showing anything.only showing arrow moving.

Comment: That's why you need to know what value you are getting in `selectedStatus`. can you write `MessageBox.Show(selectedStatus);` before `if (selectedStatus  == "New")` and see what is displayed in the MessageBox?

Comment: yes I have done it. I put the index 4 because this is the order,  defect id, description, created date, created time, steps to reproduce, status

Comment: as per the order you shared... `status` is at 6th position starting from 0

Comment: I add this.MessageBox.Show(selectedStatus);  it shows empty. Nothing data in here. Only shows message box

Comment: That's the issue. as per the order you shared... status is at 6th position starting from 0. So try putting 6 in `senderGrid[3, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();`

Comment: Thank you so much. I have put the wrong index it should be 5, not 4. Now it is work fine